# Pig: issue with REPLACE

Tags: replace, foreach, apache-pig

Below is how my data looks like:

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245

unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985

199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085

burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0
```

Below is the Pig code:

```
loadFulldata = LOAD '/root/Kennadi-Project/Kennadi-data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (fullline:chararray);

extractData = FOREACH loadFulldata GENERATE FLATTEN (REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(fullline,'(.*) - - (.*) -(.*)] "(.*)" (.*) (.*)'));

rowdata = FOREACH extractData GENERATE $0 as host,$1 as datetime,$2 as timezone,$3 as responseurl,$4 as responsecode,$5 as response data;
```

My extractData looks like:

```
(199.72.81.55,[01/Jul/1995:00:00:01,0400,GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0,200,6245)
(unicomp6.unicomp.net,[01/Jul/1995:00:00:06,0400,GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0,200,3985)
(199.120.110.21,[01/Jul/1995:00:00:09,0400,GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0,200,4085)
(burger.letters.com,[01/Jul/1995:00:00:11,0400,GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0,304,0)
(199.120.110.21,[01/Jul/1995:00:00:11,0400,GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0,200,4179)
(burger.letters.com,[01/Jul/1995:00:00:12,0400,GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0,304,0)
```

When I use `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` I cannot remove '[' from the data, how can I achieve that?

In addition, I tried to remove '[' using `REPLACE` function like so:

```
rowdata = FOREACH extractData GENERATE $0 as host,$1 as datadatetime,$2 as timezone,$3 as responseurl,$4 as responsecode,$5 as response data;

newdata = FOREACH rowdata GENERATE REPLACE(datadatetime,'[','');
```

But I am getting below warning:

```
2016-01-05 05:10:13,758 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning USING_OVERLOADED_FUNCTION 1 time(s).
2016-01-05 05:10:13,758 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_CHARARRAY 1 time(s).
```

I think it is because I haven't defined any datatype for `datadatetime`, how do I define datatype in foreach?

Comment: Have you tried this?
rowdata = FOREACH extractData GENERATE $0 as host:chararray,$1 as datetime:chararray, ....

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem. You try solving it using a regular expression. You now have two problems.

Seriously though, after trying it this seems to just be a problem with the regex. Using

```
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(fullline,'(.*) - - \\[(.*) -(.*)\\] "(.*)" (.*) (.*)')
```

did the trick for me.

Result:

```
(199.72.81.55,01/Jul/1995:00:00:01,0400,GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0,200,6245)
(unicomp6.unicomp.net,01/Jul/1995:00:00:06,0400,GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0,200,3985)
(199.120.110.21,01/Jul/1995:00:00:09,0400,GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0,200,4085)
(burger.letters.com,01/Jul/1995:00:00:11,0400,GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0,304,0)
```